# Running Perl scripts from a file in linux

Tags: perl, file

I'm in Linux (CentOS) trying to run a basic Perl script from a file.  I am getting an error.  I think it has something to do with the syntax, but I can't figure it out.

```
$ perl -e 'print "Hello World\n";'
```

This runs fine and will print Hello World on the next line.  However, when I put this into vi and save it as perlOne, exactly the same (perl -e 'print "Hello World\n";') and run the command:

```
$ perl perlOne
```

I get the error: "syntax error at perlOne line 1, near "perl -e   -- Execution of perlOne aborted due to compilation errors."

It's the same line, but it does not work in the file.

I'm working through the Perl tutorial from Linux Pro Magazine - which is where I got this from.

Comment: You'll probably want to avoid using switches (in this way) and command calls to `perl` in an actual Perl script... :)

Comment: since you are already running the file with Perl, you only need the statement in the file: `print "Hello World\n";`

Comment: Yep @perreal - that did it.  Guess I was doubling up some of the commands/syntax.

Comment: You can either use perreal's solution (probably the best) or run `$ perlOne` as a shell script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command-line switch `-e` allows you to run code from the command line, instead of having to write your program to a file and then execute it.

```
$ perl -e 'print "Hello World\n";'
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

If you want to run it from your file you will need to write it differently:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $message = 'Hello World';
print $message . "\n";

# You can also make it directly
print "Hello World\n";
```

While I do not recommend it can also be written as:

```
print "Hello World\n";
```

Comment: how to runt the file using . tried using `perl file-name`

Comment: @SanKrish what do you mean using `.`? Like `perl ./filename`? ***Would be better if you make a new question about your issue.***